# incomplete merge of accounts

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

In my [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5469441/piyush?tab=accounts) there are two accounts for Magento, though both redirects to same profile on desktop version but I am unable to view my profile in Stackexchange mobile App. This two exist from a long time (more than 2 Years) When I have changed my associated email address.

Comment: thank you very much @Oded

Comment: I think you should check this on https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Marius it is resolved now, as updated by Oded